# add the Id of elements with a specific class to an multidimensional array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multidimensional-array, slider

I am developing a slider plugin. I want support for multiple sliders on one page. I first have to find the id's of the sliders on the page and then i have to store the active slide of the slider in an array.

This an example of the html:

```
<div class="slider" id="slider1">...</div>
<div class="slider" id="slider2">...</div>
<div class="slider" id="slider3">...</div>
```

if someone loads the page an array should be created that looks like this:

```
var sliders = [
  ['slider1','1'],
  ['slider2','1'],
  ['slider3','1']
];
```

If a press for example the right arrow on a slider. I add one to slider to that id in the slider array

If for instance slider 3 shows slide 3 the array should be like:

```
var sliders = [
  ['slider1','1'],
  ['slider2','1'],
  ['slider3','3']
];
```

I am open for jquery or just JavaScript solutions. I can't figure out how this would work. I hope someone can help me.

So my question is: How do i let Javascript make an array when page gets loaded with all the sliders and their shown slide.

here is a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/a7c7opnz/1/

Thank you,

Comment: How looks like your slides??? `class="slide"`? How do you know which slide is active? Etc... This is completly uncomplete question, provide minimalistic code to replicate your issue

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can easily grab all sliders and use a for loop to create your array. In the for loop you can use the push method from javascript (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

```
var singleSlider;
var arraySliders;
var activeSlide;
var sliders = $('.slider');

for(var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++){
activeslide = YOUR ACTIVE SLIDE CODE;
 singleSlider = [sliders[i].attr('id'), activeSlide];
 arraySliders.push(singleSlider);
}
```

Not sure if this will work or not, didn't test this. But you should get the idea..